# How do I map the values from two CSV files in python using their ID?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to map the data between two CSV file into one output results or a new output file. first file contains list of airport codes and their corresponding Latitude and Longitude. the second file has passengers details including their departure and destination airport codes.

First CSV file example:

```py
A_code Latitude Longitude
ATL   33.636719   -84.428067
PEK   40.080111   116.584556
LHR   51.4775     -0.461389
```

Second CSV file example:

```py
P_id  f_id from dest
usr1    1   ATL PEK
usr1    2   PEK LHR
usr2    1   ATL PEK
usr3    3   LHR ATL
usr2    3   LHR ATL
```

What I have done so far is:

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd

colnames = ['Pass_id', 'f_id', 'from', 'dest']
L1 = pd.read_csv(r"Passenger_data.csv",names=colnames)
colnames = ['f_id', 'from_lat', 'from_lon']
L2 = pd.read_csv(r"airports_data.csv",names=colnames)
result = pd.merge(L1, L2, how='left',on='from')

colnames = ['Pass_id', 'f_id', 'from', 'dest']
L1 = pd.read_csv(r"Passenger_data.csv",names=colnames)
colnames = ['f_id', 'dest_lat', 'dest_lon']
L2 = pd.read_csv(r"airports_data.csv",names=colnames)
result2 = pd.merge(L1, L2, how='left',on='dest')
```

and then I combined the results of result+result2.

```py
final= result['Pass_id']+' '+result['f_id']+' '+result['from_lat'].apply(str)+' '+result['from_lon'].apply(str)+' '+result2['dest_lat'].apply(str)+' '+result2['dest_lon'].apply(str)
```

I've achieved the results that I am looking for but it is a long and non-practical process. I believe that there is a faster way to do that. the expected results after combining (mapping) should look like this

```py
P_id  f_id from  dest   from_lat     from_lon    dest_lat  dest_lon
usr1    1   ATL   PEK  33.636719   -84.428067  40.080111   116.584556
usr1    2   PEK   LHR  40.080111   116.584556  51.4775     -0.461389
usr2    1   ATL   PEK  33.636719   -84.428067  40.080111   116.584556
usr3    3   LHR   ATL  51.4775     -0.461389   33.636719   -84.428067
usr2    3   LHR   ATL  51.4775     -0.461389   33.636719   -84.428067
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('airports_data.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('Passenger_data.csv')
df = df.set_index('A_code')

df1['from_lat'] = df1['from'].map(df['Latitude'])
df1['from_lon'] = df1['from'].map(df['Longitude'])
df1['dest_lat'] = df1['dest'].map(df['Latitude'])
df1['dest_lon'] = df1['dest'].map(df['Longitude'])
```

output will be

```
    P_id    f_id    from    dest    from_lat    from_lon    dest_lat    dest_lon
0   usr1    1   ATL PEK 33.636719   -84.428067  40.080111   116.584556
1   usr1    2   PEK LHR 40.080111   116.584556  51.477500   -0.461389
2   usr2    1   ATL PEK 33.636719   -84.428067  40.080111   116.584556
3   usr3    3   LHR ATL 51.477500   -0.461389   33.636719   -84.428067
4   usr2    3   LHR ATL 51.477500   -0.461389   33.636719   -84.428067
```